# Best way to compare two large list, C#

Tags: c#, database, list, linq

This is for one of my ETL project to sync two database, some table is 4G, so ETL job just load updated data to insert or update, that works fine, but the source table will delete some records, and I want to delete from my table too. What I did is:

```
List<long> SourceIDList; // load all ID from source table
List<long> MyIDList; // load all ID from my table
var NeedRemoveIDList = MyIDList.Except( SourceIDList );
foreach(var ID in NeedRemoveIDList)
   // remove from my table
```

The code logic work, but load ID from 4G table to List will through "out of memory" exception, is there better way?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: So you got out of memory before even trying to calculate the difference? Supposing you are low on resources for any reason, but you could open remote cursors on ordered lists of id's in both sources, you could traverse them in batches. As long as both are ordered, you can find the gaps. But if you can do it, just place a table in the source database that collects the deleted id's with a trigger. With some transaction finetuning you can process that periodically without blocking further deletions.

Comment: The process space is normally 2GB so you do unhealthy things with trying to load that much data into memory. Couldn't you just do that on the database?

Comment: Do not do bulk operations on databases in code! Keep them to the DBMS if at all possible. If you got to do filtering, always do it during the queries. Every Decent DBMS should have some way to important a table (when in doubt, csv). Doing that in code will just end up worse in every single metric. At least you will be adding the Network transmission time to the thing. At worst, you run into memory and object size limits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments, I end up doing this in database, I insert two list into temp table, and use SQL to compare them, take some time to insert data, but since this is ETL job, few extra minutes is OK.